# What do I need to set up a remote terminal

Tags: 14.04, server, remote-desktop, remote-access

So I have looked at the other questions that seem similar to this one, but they don't answer it for me. I do not believe that VNC or Team Viewer is appropriate because I am not looking for a desktop sharing solution. I think that I need some sort of remote X terminal solution, but I can't find how to set something like that up.

This is what I am looking for:

Local host: Windows 7
Remote host: Ubuntu 14.04LTS Server (headless)

I am looking for something that works similarly to Windows RDP.

I want to be able to connect to the remote and have a login screen show up which requires me to enter my network user id and password, or my user id and password on the remote computer. I do not believe VNC works because it appears to require a global password to be configured for access to the remote. If a second person wants to connect, they should be required to enter their own user id and password.

I found a document for Multiseat X configuration. This is close to what I want, but that appears to apply to allowing multiple concurrent logins to a local machine rather than multiple concurrent logins to a remote machine. I don't know enough about Linux or specifically Ubuntu to port the multiseat configuration to a remote machine.

I am willing to consider VNC or TeamViewer if someone can show me how to configure them for multiple concurrent remote seats. That is multiple users logged on to individual non-shared sessions.

Comment: Whats wrong with ssh?

Comment: ssh and scp work for me, some folks just need the GUI. I am looking for a GUI desktop that works like ssh. Instead of a command line, I would get a GUI desktop.

Comment: Your perceptions of VNC may have been skewed by its use as a *desktop sharing* platform. You can use VNC, with each user logging in independently via SSH and then starting his/her own independent stand-alone VNC server process (vnc4server or tightvncserver for example) that is tunnelled back to the remote client.

Answer (score 1):

On my Raspberry Pi I use xrdp sometimes. Quick search shows works with Ubuntu.

[image: Screenscap of xrdp running Ubuntu]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at [Remmina Remote Desktop Client](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/). It works pretty much exactly like Windows RDP: you can interact with the remote desktop GUI on your local machine as if the remote operating system were running on your local machine.

Comment: Do you have a link to a Windows 7 version of the client? This looks like a Linux only package.

Comment: I overlooked that it's your local system with Windows. What is wrong with Windows RDP then? And if you're using Ubuntu server on your remote, you won't have a GUI for your remote OS to begin with.

Comment: will windows RDP connct with Ubuntu server out of the box? what do I need to make it work?

Comment: Windows RDP usually requires a domain name (or some kind of identifying address where your server is), login name and password. But, as far as I know, Ubuntu Server out of the box has no GUI, it is a terminal environment, so you will have no GUI for your remote connection and may as well SSH.

Comment: I installed the minimal ubuntu-desktop package without recommends. What do I need to add to get RDP to function.